# How to get Json data from java website by using Codeigniter3?

Tags: java, php, json, httpclient, codeigniter-3

I'm going to select data which return value from third party website as below **Json objects** format and that website build in Java languages and tomcat database.

**Issue** How to get contain from that websites?

**Server description**

**URL**:[http://103.5.126.24/PalmHallServer/coodraw/coodraw!queryAllProduct.action](http://http103.5.126.24/PalmHallServer/coodraw/coodraw!queryAllProduct.action)

**Return data** json objects, luckDrawProductList for all product information array,

```
{
    "LuckDrawProductList": [
        {
            "BaseTime": 20140119133000,
            "CommissionRatio": 10,
            "DeductBetCount": 1,
            "Detail": "You can enter any amount between ...",
            "Enable": 1,
            "FreeResDiscount": 1,
            "LotteryTime": 20151016164500,
            "LuckDrawDesc": "DRAW1",
            "LuckDrawDiscount": 1,
            "MaxLuckNumLen": 5,
            "MaxMoney": 2000000,
            "MinLuckNumLen": 5,
            "MinMoney": 100,
            "NextStartTime": "2015-10-16 12:00:00",
            "NextStopTime": "2015-10-16 16:15:00",
            "OpenDrawType": -1,
            "PeriodUnit": 1,
            "PeriodUnitNum": 1,
            "Price": 40,
            "ProductCode": "DRAW1",
            "ProductDesc": "Draw1",
            "ProductEndTime": 20990119163000,
            "ProductId": 11111,
            "ProductType": 11,
            "Rate": 0,
            "ResTmplProductId": 11111,
            "StopTime": 1800,
            "ValidPeriod": 2
        }
    ],
    "Period": "201510161645"
}
```

Comment: are you using Gson? @Cambodia_channel

Comment: I want to httpClient in PHP because my teamwork seguested me to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try code below

```
$URL = "http://103.5.126.24/PalmHallServer/coodraw/coodraw!queryAllProduct.action";

$content = file_get_contents($URL);    // get json data using file_get_content
$content_arr = json_decode($content); // json data to php array.
```

OR if you wish to use curl

```
$s = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$this->_url);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);    
$result = curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);
$content_arr = json_decode($result); // json data to php array.
```

Then you could print_r($content_arr) and check "LuckDrawProductList" the key or access $content_arr['LuckDrawProductList][0]

Comment: I got errors
Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content() in D:\My data\project\wamp\www\lottery\application\views\templates\content.php on line 83

Comment: welcome and sorry for file_get_content , I have changed it to file_get_contents